# Finder injection with mach_inject, change the injection message

Tags: macos, finder

I have written a finder injection bundle and I have signed the binary with developer id certificate. Injection works fine but I see a permission message while injecting the code as "Developer Tools Acces is trying to take......." and I would like to have some user friendly message here instead of this technical wordings. Anybody have any idea how to change this message?![I was not allowed to add image here other I would have added an image of that permission message].

Also this permission can also be seen on each login into OSX, can we change the behavior, so that we don't show this message on each login into OSX machine? This is how dropbox have achieved and I don't know how to achieve this as there is no technical documentation regarding this. Your help is much appriciated!.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [link](http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/html/xcode-users@lists.apple.com/2009-09/msg00291.html). add your username to `_developer` group.

```
sudo dscl . append /Groups/_developer GroupMembership <username>
```